# Show element in hiddens elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***HTML***

```
<body>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span id="show">aaaaaa</span>
</body>
```

***JS***

```
$('body').hide();

$('#show').show();
```

Why doesn't this work? How can I make it work?

Now all is hidden, but if I use `$('#show').show();` it should make `#show` visible. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I want hide all elements without #show, but I can't modify the HTML.

Comment: You can't show something that is in a hidden container. If you hide the body, everything inside the body will be hidden.

Comment: If all you wanted was to make the `#show` element and its descendants visible, and the siblings of `#show` and their descendants hidden, then all you need is `$('body > *:not(#show)').hide();`. Your accepted answer will traverse the entire page and hide all elements even though they are already invisible.

Comment: ...[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11637884/1106925) is far better if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide all elements without `id="show"`, you can use the [`not` function](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('body').find('*').not('#show').hide();
```

or the [`:not` psuedoselector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('body').find(':not("#show")').hide();
```

Edit: to also show all children of #show, add that to the not selector:

```
$('body').find('*').not('#show, #show > *').hide();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7gm/3/

Comment: thanks, this is ok, but how can i make this also for all children #show? http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7gm/

Comment: What merit do you find in hiding a parent and *all* its ancestor elements when hiding the parent effectively hides the ancestors as well?

Comment: @amnotiam the goal is to hide every element on the page except #show and its children elements.

Comment: I really don't think that is what OP was after. When hiding an element, all its descendants are automatically hidden. I don't think OP understood how to hide the children of `body` but exclude `#show`. There's really no point in hiding an element *and* its ancestors, and it's terribly inefficient to do so.

Comment: @amnotiam its *not* hiding an element and its ancestors, and its exactly what the OP asked for (hence the accept)

Comment: @jbabey: Unless you believe that the HTML in the question is the actual code, then yes, if there are any ancestors, it will be hiding the parents and all the ancestors. Any practical purpose for code like this would be very rare. If OP doesn't understand how to do something properly, they'll likely accept an answer that seems to work if it has votes.

Comment: ...or I meant "descendants", not "ancestors". Point is that there's no sense in filtering through all elements on the page and applying a "hide" to each one when they're already effectively hidden by an ancestor.

Answer (score 4):

Because `#show` is inside `body`, which is not visible.
`body` defines the document's body and it contains all your elements, so if you hide it you'll hide all your elements.
Try to hide just the elements you want to.

Answer (score 4):

By setting `display: none` on the `document.body` (that is what `.hide()` basically does), the second call to `#show` becomes pretty much irrelevant, because the parent is still hidden (`body`).

You would need to select all elements, without the specific node and hide those.

```
$(document.body).contents().not('#show, #show *').hide();
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7gm/2/ this not working. How can i use this also for all children elements #show?

Comment: @PaulJeggor: Yes sorry, by using `*` I also included the `body` again. Updated the line, works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('body').contents().hide();
$('#show').show();​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wSgMt/)**

This will hide all children of the body and show the element with ID `show`.

Comment: Why are you using `.contents()` instead of `.children()`?

Comment: @amnotiam - because "Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents()." In other words, belt and suspenders.

Comment: But you can't style text nodes, so it'll have no effect. BTW, I think this answer is far better than the upvoted ones... just that `.contents()` seemed an odd choice. I'll +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the other elements, not the whole body.

```
$('span').hide();
$('#show').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try appending span after the body tag, like this.

```
<body>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span>test</span>
    <span id="show">aaaaaa</span>
</body>    

$('body span').hide();

$('#show').show();
```

[jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/44yFM/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').find('*').not('#show, #show > *').hide();
```